# Clojure Emacs Connecting to Remote REPL

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl

When using plain repl with `tramp` I can navigate to a remote directory and exetute  `inferior-lisp` and it launches a `inferior-lisp` process on the remote. With nrepl I can start the repl on the remote machine using `lein repl` than connect to it using `nrepl-jack-in` but the problem is with nrepl I have to setup firewall rules or use ssh and forward ports so I can jack in. With inferior-lisp and tramp method I do not need to do anything special just hit `M-x inferior-lisp` and I am set. Is there a way to achieve similar behaviour using nrepl and tramp?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your settings, most likely `inferior-lisp` invokes a local process. 
If you just want to work on your Clojure project locally, I would recommend to download the project folder from the remote machine and repl locally using `nrepl-jack-in`.

Comment: `inferior-lisp` when launched from a tramp buffer executes a remote process and connects std in/out to inferior lisp buffer it does not execute a local process.